# Over a left V-ring, why is every module containing a simple essential submodule is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-isomorphism, module-isomorphism

I've tried to prove the statement $R$ is a $V-$ring if and only if every module containing a simple essential submodule is simple. I know that a ring $R$ is called as a $V-$ring if every simple $R$ module is injective. However, I cannot prove the above statement by just using this definition of $V-$ring. Is there anyone can give me a hint for this, at least an extra information about injectivity or $V-$ring that I can use for the proof of that statement?

Comment: You should NOT change the wording of a question so that it invalidates existing answers.  Proofread your questions before you post them.

Comment: Seeing now that it was in the title up front, I see it was an honest mistake, but really it is a good lesson in making sure your question is written correctly.  People tend to focus on the body of the question when answering it.

Answer (score 4):

"$R$ is a V-ring if and only if every module containing a simple submodule is simple." is a false theorem.

For example, the ring $R=F_2\times F_2$ is a semisimple ring, and so all of its modules contain simple modules.  Semisimple rings are also V-rings, but obviously not all of its modules can be simple.

*To address the new version of the question*

"$R$ is a V-ring if and only if every module containing an essential simple submodule is simple."

This is obvious since injective modules are summands of their supermodules. No summand can be essential unless it is already the entire module.  So if a module contains an essential injective submodule, that submodule is already the entire module.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the theorem. It should be " R is a $V-$ ring if and only if every module containing a simple essential submodule is simple."

Comment: Thanks for your answer and  warning. Here, the term "supermodule of a module" is so new for me. Is it a new term or may be a different name of any other known terms? When I search it, it is defined as a graded-module by using some other new terms for me and I couldn't get actually what it is.

Comment: @HakanŞanal In English, "super-" and "sub-" are opposites in this context.  If $A\subseteq B$, you can say $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $B$ is a superset of $A$.  I will admit it is probably not often used in print. I am just applying linguistic conventions.